# Detect HashTag inside ListView Using Linkify

Tags: android, android-fragments, hashtag, linkify

I did implement this tutorial http://sourabhsoni.com/implementing-hashtags-in-android-application/

in My app  But i converted my app from Activities to Fragments

so What i have to do is to make the HashLink Click  open a Specific  Fragment.

Comment: check the link you posted is giving error!